# How do I keep one div from affecting the vertical position of another's bootstrap form elements?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a custom, two-column layout for a page going on a site that uses Bootstrap.  I've done  the css for the columns myself, since Bootstrap doesn't appear to handle a "one fixed, one fluid" layout natively.  This works nicely, except when I try to put a form in the larger, fluid column:

```
<style>
    #filterColumn {
        border: 1px solid #ececec;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 20px 40px 20px;
        padding: 62px 10px 10px 10px;
        width: 216px;
    }

    #detailsColumn {
        border: 1px solid #ececec;
        margin: 0px 20px 40px 275px;
        padding: 72px 10px 10px 10px;
    }
</style>

<body>

<div id="filterColumn">
    <h4>Headline</h4>
    <p>
        Some text in here.
    </p>
</div>

<div id="detailsColumn">
    <h2>Here are my busted fields:</h2>

    <form id="detailForm" class="form-horizontal" action="/action" method="post">

    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="input0" class="control-label">Input 0</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input id="input0" name="input1" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="input1" class="control-label">Input 1</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input id="input1" name="input1" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

Bootstrap styles the form elements and includes some clearing stuff to make it all work.  The issue for me is that my fixed div on the left affects the clearing of elements in the fluid div on the right.  Essentially the first row of the form is positioned correctly, but all subsequent rows are pushed down below the content of the left-hand div, despite not being in it.  The result is that I have a large, ugly gap in the list of inputs.  I've made a jsFiddle so you can see exactly what I'm talking about:

http://jsfiddle.net/ABJ53/

What's the appropriate way to fix this?  Originally I just set the left-hand column to absolute positioning, since it's always flush top-left.  When I added a footer to the page, however, it started overlapping the two, which isn't acceptable.

Is there a Bootstrap way to fix this, or are there attributes I should be adding/overriding myself in order to solve the problem?

Comment: Why aren't you using the bootstrap grid thne?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, with the grid you have to commit whole rows to be either fully fluid or fully fixed, which doesn't work for what I'm doing.  I'm trying for a fixed left column with a fluid right column.  If I can use the existing grid system for that, of course, please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to add float left for details colomn.. I added float left to both id's on [your example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ABJ53/3/) and it works.

```
#filterColumn
{
    background-color: #fefefe;
    border: 1px solid #ececec;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    float: left;
    width: 216px;
}

#detailsColumn {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    border: 1px solid #ececec;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    float: left;
    width: 556px;
}
```